# Curiously Recurring Template Pattern Bug in VS2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, crtp

Why would this code not compile in VS2010?

```
struct Base
{
    void foo0() { }
};
template<typename BASE> struct Derived : BASE
{
    void foo1() { foo0(); }
};
int main()
{
    Derived<Base> ddd;
    ddd.foo1();
    return 0;   
}
```

It compiles just fine in other compilers. It also compiles if I call foo0 with the help of this: this->foo0();

Comment: This is NOT Curiously Recurring Template Pattern... CRTP works with other way around: you call derived method from base class.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that the reason behind this behavior is Language Extensions compiler option (/Za). So if Language Extensions are disabled, above code would not compile. What is strange here is, this must be part of the C++ language and not the MS Language Extensions.

Hope this helps someone...

Comment: MSVC was known to compile a code which was not standard compliant and I am pretty sure this code would compile on older releases. I guess Microsoft finally got to improve their compiler to work as standard mandates and they probably moved the old behaviour to be included as their 'extension' to allow older code to compile. You have to qualify foo0 with this-> or BASE:: for your code to comply with C++ standard.

Comment: Tomek, do you base your comment on this particular case of CRTP or this would also apply to any base-derived pair (even if no templates are involved). It seems strange to have standard which is not clear about this and/or forces you to always qualify. This will make inheritance useless or this-> mandatory in order to have consistent code. One would think c++ would be evolving towards ease of use by developer and not ease of compiling the code by the compiler. Thanks for your response though.

Comment: I don't remember exact wording but shortly speaking you need to qualify all inherited names which come from base class which is dependent on template parameter. As Yakk mentioned the compiler doesn't have a way to know that foo0 is derived when the template is parsed as it didn't see base class yet. Therefore it will treat foo0 as belonging to enclosing namespace and will spit an error if it was not declared.

Answer (score 1):

At the point of declaration of `Derived<BASE>::foo1()`, it does not know what `BASE` is.  It then tries to figure out what `foo0` is.  There is no `foo0` in view -- or worse it finds a global `foo0` to call.  This is an error.

When you instead call `this->foo0()` you inform the compiler that you want to find it as a method.

Comment: Well, it seems this type of explicit qualification is not needed by clang or ms when extensions are enabled, so it must be quite easy to be sorted out by the compiler. And if this type of CRTP is supported by the language, they should make sure implicit access to BASE is in the standard as well. It will just make life easier:) Thanks for your comment though.